# ggplot title: not able to add margin on the left side. Is this a bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to put the title of a ggplot inside the panel. I have something like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This is my title\nsecond part") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = -40, l = 40))
  )
```

I am not sure why I am not able to give some margin on the left side of my title. I tried many values, permutations but it does not seem to work. I can center it if needed by using `hjust = 0.5` but not able to just provide a margin on the left side.

Comment: Is using something like: `hjust = 0.05` an option?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a bug, it doesn't make sense to me why this wouldn't work. Here is a workaround though using the `ggtext` package. Might have to fiddle around a bit with the exact margin values.

```
library(ggtext)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "This is my title\nsecond part") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_textbox(margin = margin(t = 5.5, b= -40, l = 40))
  )
```